# How do I achieve deep blue light night during the day effect?

Tags: effect

I'm trying to learning about ND, I want to know if this picture was taken with a ND, or what kind of filter?

The effect I'm looking for is the deep blue and the "night" aspect. I'm wonder also how the road is so blured, a patter of grey and an exaltating yellow.

If this picture is photoshoped, there is any way to take a picture like this one only with the camera?

Please edit my question to be compliant of the topic "What kind of effect..." question.
Thanks a lot!

[image]

Comment: Maybe [How do you make a shot look like it was taken at night?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/8398/how-do-you-make-a-shot-look-like-it-was-taken-at-night) will help?

Comment: mmm I think is not the effect that I'm looking for, or I can't see that effect here. Because the sky has a deep blue but the yellow of the road is too high too

Comment: I'm almost certain that the road is smoothed in post-processing and the line is likewise drawn-in. It could be that it's very freshly paved and painted, and may be highly reflective and then just pushed up to extremes in the processing.

Comment: oh :( so there is no way to take a similar photo in-camera? Well, the link you give me inspirated me in several ways. thanks a lot !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The particular photo you are showing was heavily altered in post production.  The fact that the water isn't glassed (blurred together) tells us that the exposure had to be rather fast and any quick exposure with an ND wouldn't look like this.  A long exposure at night with the right conditions might get something like this, but then the waves would be glassed as opposed to crisp.  The yellow is also very odd on the road.

My best guess is that they played with the colorization of the image to give it this appearance and then possibly did some matte painting as well (the yellow line on the road seems a little too perfect).

Comment: the explanation about the water is not only the answer, it teach me a lot about how conditions/configuration I've to take care to take some pictures with ND (that's is the thing I try to learn). Thanks a lot! (It's difficult learn without the filter, LOL)