# How do you turn day into night and night into day?

Tags: photoshop, photo-editing, editing, photoshop-cs6

Easily to explain hard to do.

I wonder if its possible for me to take photo of my street in the day and make it look like night because night photography is beautiful but night requires high shutter speeds which doesn't fit for tree leaves. I can add distant lights etc later through a night shot.

This idea came from my idea of filming night scenes in day with low ISO high quality and then edit them to make them look like night. Too bad I dont have RAW camera. So how well it would look like with h264?

And as the second question. How much quality/realism is it possible to do the same in night through 10 sec 20 sec and 30 sec image stacking and then make it look like it was taken in the day assuming there are no passing cars etc?

Comment: Well known technique in cinema: see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Day_for_night) for hints.

Comment: This question is a tad broad to me for this reason: The methods chosen in post really depend on lighting. The moon, as a light source, is not so different from the sun, simply less intense. The problem is that night shots introduce light sources that are not typically present during the day - so flip flopping requires a day shot to redo the light and shadows to account for multiple man-made sources and a night shot to overcome those same sources. So...can you post an example photo from which to start?

Comment: @Hueco I will soon.

Comment: Whoops wrong link. I meant https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/8398/how-do-you-make-a-shot-look-like-it-was-taken-at-night

Comment: @mattdm I think this might be a good stand alone question as it focuses on post pro specifically. No answer in that other question really touches on exact post pro to do

Comment: I think that's a lack of detail in the answers to the question, not a sign that this isn't the same thing.

Comment: Also, since day to night and night to day are entirely different, they should be separate questions — this is too broad as is

Comment: "High shutter speeds" is confusing terminology here... there is a reason photographer refer to "fast" and "slow" shutter speeds, and you will usually need slow shutter speeds at night.